# How to use Vue with Laravel 5.4 (best practice)

Tags: php, laravel, vuejs2, laravel-blade

I'm a software engineer and don't have a lot of experience with PHP or javascript. I will upgrading my skills in this so i started with a PHP framework Laravel which looks very nice in my opinion. I'm familar with the MVC principal so i can find my way in Laravel!

I created some models with corresponding controllers. I also created some blade views to display the data. I give a model object to the blade view as folows:

```
    $person = new \App\Person("Firstname", "Lastname");
    return view('personView', compact('person'));
```

I can get it done to use the person object in the blade view to display his variables with:

```
{{ $user->name }}
```

Now i tried to go one step further and want do do some stuff with Vue so i can display and manipulate the object on client side (and dispay dynamic data). Later i want to save the client side object via a action in the controller over a HTTP post or something, but fist things first...

I'm be able to create a vue object with some data in it and display it in HTML controlls for example.

So, summerized

1. i'm be able to generate my backend objects and manipulate them. I can bring them to my view and display them with {{ $obj->var }}
2. I'm be able to create Vue objects with data, and manipulating this data and show it with @{{ data }}.

My problem is that i can't get the data from the controller (which i give wat i gave to the view) into the Vue object. What is the best practice to do this? Or is this not the way to go? in that case, what is convinient to do as i read that Laravel has Vue integrated and this sounds for me that there should be a (best practice) way to achieve this?

I looked for a creat tutorial but couln'd find this. So if someone has a good tutorial to learn understanding Laravel in combination with Blade and Vue, please share!

I already tried something like this, unfortunately without any result:

```
new Vue({

    el: '#someElement',

    data: {
        person: {!! $person!!}
    }

})
```

(Using Laravel 5.4.x and Vue 2.4.x)

Comment: I'm not familiar with Laravel+Vue, but in a only VueJs side, you can't have the `data` property in the declaration of the Vue instance. Instead, you need to look up for components https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html

Answer (score 0):

You can simply pass the object to the vue component like that:

```
<my-component :person="{{ $person }}" ></my-component>
```

And your Vue component

```
<template>
   {{ person.name }}
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        props: ['person']
    }
</script>
```